# How to implement Tiling with Compute shader in Metal?

Tags: ios, kernel, gpu, metal, compute-shader

I am new to Metal and compute world. With basic understanding of GPU programming, I want to optimize texel read of input image/data. I have already tried combining multiple read and process those pixels but somehow that makes it even worse.

I have tried to combining multiple read in many ways like reading 4 in rows, columns, 2x2 in a block, 4 pixels each from different quadrant of the image, without any gain.

I found during experiments that a simple read of 4k image takes around 4.5ms on iPhone X or 11 or Pro. So I want to reduce that time in order to optimize the whole process.

I came to know about tiling local storage is quite fast and I think I can read multiple texels in this memory to process in a go later/next pass/after read completes.

My questions:

1. How can I implement Tiling with Compute Shader in Metal? Is there a sample or example code?
2. What is the possibility or optimization here?
3. Is there any other way to optimize texel read to make it faster.

Comment: Maybe check out the `gather` functions on textures. They allow you to get 4 pixel values _of a single channel_ with one fetch request.

Comment: You are unlikely to see any performance improvement as the GPU is basically waiting on memory reads and writes most of the time anyway. A plain image render using the GPU is basically just reading from memory and then writing to memory, so it is unclear what aspect of the performance you could improve on with different GPU code.